# How to make UIPickerView Rotational?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Let I have an array [1,2,3,4,5...] and i want to show it in a UIPickerView in swift. But i would like to be it rotational. For e.g after the value 5 next value will be 1, then 2 and so on. Similarly while showing the selected value 1 the previous value will be 5 & so on. To be exact I would like to have the picker view like following 
->1->
|   2   |
|   3   |
|   4   |
|   5   |
|   6   |
 <- 7<-